# How to create a custom error that's a subtype of another custom error, like inherited?

Tags: go, error-handling

For a given custom error type:

```golang
type CustomError struct {
    // Err optionally wraps the original error.
    Err error `json:"-"`

    // Human readable message.
    Message string `json:"message" validate:"required,gte=3"`

    // StatusCode is a valid HTTP status code, e.g.: 404.
    StatusCode int `json:"-"`
}
```

Which implements both `Error() string`, and the `Unwrap() error` interface, also have a factory:

```golang
func NewCustomError(m string, s int, e error) *CustomError {}
```

How to create another "type", based on `CustomType` - let's call it `FailedTo` for errors such as *"Failed to created X"* which will have by default:

- A prefixed `Message` with `Failed to`
- Status code of `500`

and on top of that, another one, such as `FailedToCreateSomething` in a way where....

```golang
func createSomething() error {
    return FailedToCreateSomething(errors.New("File is busy"))
}

errCreateSomething := createSomething()
```

...`errCreateSomething` is type of `FailedToCreateSomething`, also `FailedTo`, and `CustomError`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's distill the example down to it's essence.

```golang
package customerror

import (
    "errors"
)

type CustomError struct {
    Aux string
    Err error
}

func (cE *CustomError) Error() string { /*...*/ }
func (err *CustomError) Unwrap() error { return err.Err }

func NewFailedToError(aux string, err error) error {
    return &CustomError{ Aux: aux, Err: err }
}

var FailedToWriteToFile = NewFailedToError("write to file", nil)
```

We can now get to the question in the gist:

```golang
// Some function just for demonstration.
func WriteToFile() error {
    // Something caused some error..
    errSome := errors.New("Failed to open file")

    // How can I set the `err` value of `FailedToWriteToFile` to `errSome`
    // without setting that for all `FailedToWriteToFile` instances (pointer)?
    // while still making it of `FailedToWriteToFile` type (errors.Is(errSome, FailedToWriteToFil))?
    return FailedToWriteToFile
}
```

Let's reframe this question to how do I make an `errSome` with a new message where `errors.Is(errSome, FailedToWriteToFil)` holds.

We can checkout the documentation of [`errors.Is`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is):

> Is reports whether any error in err's chain matches target.
>
> The chain consists of err itself followed by the sequence of errors obtained by repeatedly calling Unwrap.
>
> An error is considered to match a target if it is equal to that target or if it implements a method Is(error) bool such that Is(target) returns true.
>
> An error type might provide an Is method so it can be treated as equivalent to an existing error. For example, if MyError defines
>
> func (m MyError) Is(target error) bool { return target == fs.ErrExist }
>
> then Is(MyError{}, fs.ErrExist) returns true. See syscall.Errno.Is for an example in the standard library.

This gives us two paths. One of the paths is to put `FailedToWriteToFile` on the Unwrap chain. CustomError has enough fields for this if we use the Err field to point to `FailedToWriteToFile`, e.g.

```
&CustomError{Aux: "Failed to open file", Err: FailedToWriteToFile}
```

Unwrap() on this is == to `FailedToWriteToFile`. FWIW Aux could be field of type error if you are trying to capture an error value coming from another source. As long as the Unwrap() chain leads to the `FailedToWriteToFile` eventually.

The other path is to define an `Is` predicate on `CustomError`. There are a lot of possible predicates to choose from. A simple one is that all *CustomError are considered equivalent. That would be:

```golang
func (e *CustomError) Is(target error) bool {
  _, ok := target.(*CustomError)
  return ok
}
```

Comment: Tim, I updated the question, for better clarity of what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you for your previously well-detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    logger "log"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

var log = logger.Default()

func TestErrorWrapping(t *testing.T) {
    _, err := os.ReadFile("wrong file path")
    if err != nil {
        // custom error with wrapped a source error
        err = fmt.Errorf("can't read file, %w", err)
        // print it
        log.Printf("something went wrong, %s", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Output:

> something went wrong, can't read file, open wrong file path: The system cannot find the file specified.